# pdftotext for firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, poppler, xpdf

I need to extract text from pdf and for that on my local system i am using pdftotext(poppler) (on ubuntu 18.4 LTS) now i want to deploy the function to Firebase Functions but firebase functions does not have it by default.

Is there any portable version of pdftotext(poppler) as standalone executable so i can `spawn` it in firebase functions?

Can't use xpdf as it does not allow to extract text but poppler does.

Is there any portable(without any dependency) version of pdftotext from poppler ?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can try this library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse

Comment: @Mario hii, there no option to provide password and i have used it but it is terribly slow. Can you help me to build portable version of pdftotext from poppler ? I've been struggling around this. Have tried prebuilt binaries from here https://github.com/johanub/Lambda-poppler-precompiled but whenever i try to run error popups `can't find libpoppler.so.9'` please look at it.